# overridden SonataUserBundle not working properly

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-sonata

i had install SontaUserBundle i follow the document n i created

now what i want to add oneToMany relationship inside user class

```
/**
 * Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User;
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser{

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */

    protected $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Bansri\AssetBundle\Entity\statusQues", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $statusQues;


}
```

but when i am running

app/console  doctrine:generate:entities ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User

it's not generate get and add functions 
and when i manually crated that get and add function its returning null

is somting wrong with my codes

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that

```
app/console  doctrine:generate:entities ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User
```

isn't the right cli-command.

Moreover, where are you adding that relationship? Looking at your code, seem that you write this directly into Sonata Bundle and this isn't correct.
There is a better (and "good practice oriented") way for do this and consist in create a new user class and extends BaseUser (pretty like you're doin' right now) but directly into your bundle.

Then, you have to run

```
app/console  doctrine:generate:entities YourBundleName
```

Comment: i had override SonataUserBundle inside Application folder using SonataEasyExtendsBundle

and i am written doctrine relation annotation there

and this cli is working fine it only generate functions of property  of that Bundle entities i.e User